# I need to place admit date values in the discharge date column where ever discharge date is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

Used this query but it didn't help me

```
                 Update table name 
                 set AdmitDate = DischargeDate
                 where DischargeDate is NULL
```

i'm trying to put this statement down below where clause  or after bcp commands above end command

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What exactly "didn't help me" means? Error? Updated wrong rows? Updated no rows? Updated correct rows but value is something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you just have the `set` backwards:

```
Update t 
    set DischargeDate = AdmitDate
    where DischargeDate is NULL;
```

Comment: It is not helping me sir